# How to use scale in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text. It comprise of 3 columns:

```
1. student number
2. midterm grade
3. final grade

variable=$(cat $1 | awk 'NR=='$j' {print (($2+$3)/2)}' )
```

How I can make the result after 3 digit:

```
Example: 123123  50  55
result: 52.500
```

After I want to check every result , It is bigger than 50 or not.

Answer (score 1):

I propose:

```
awk '{ printf("%.3f\n", ($2+$3)/2 ) }' example.txt
```

Output: `52.500`

Comment: I want to use every value .If I use your code , It write all answers. Example If there are 5 record , ıt write all answers. I want to check every value , ıt is bigger than 50 or not.

Comment: I saw your edit. I answered your original question. In my opinion it's not clear what you want to do. After this new check you want to print the result or you will add another piece of question until you complete your homework? Please, be more specific in your questions!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the grades greater than `50` you'd do something like:

```
awk '{sum=($2+$3)/2 ; split(sum,a,"."); if(a[1] > 50) printf("%.3f\n", sum)}' grades
```

Store the result in the `sum` variable. Use `split` function to match the first part before the `.` dot and print the result

In case you want to print student's number you'd modify the `printf` line as follow:

`printf("Student: %s\t%.3f\n", $1, sum)`

Comment: I believe most people consider 50.5 to be greater than 50 but your code doesn't. awk uses floating-point so just do `sum>50` but if you really want to compare only the integer part `int(sum)>50` is clearer and also works for values where CONVFMT uses 'scientific' form but your code thinks 1234567.5 is less than 50.